# Big doors in Arx Fatalis

Tags: arx-fatalis

Arx Fatalis is my first and favorite game and there are a lot of secrets and one of its is a set of big doors around a tavern.
Does anyone know what is behind the big doors? Some players says that there is a key opening that door. But what is after that?

[Here is video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5fEkFeE6sg) of that doors

Comment: Can you please post a little more detail about where the doors are located, for example, which tavern?

Comment: Here is video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5fEkFeE6sg

Comment: You can edit your question to include that video. :) Just hit the "edit" link underneath the tags, and it will allow you to make adjustments to your question. You can just place the bare youtube link in the body of the question and it will automatically display the video for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well its one of the lesser known easter eggs in Arx Fatalis. 
To open that big Door you need a special key, this key is dropped by King Lunshire (yes you can kill and loot him)

This special key opens the large door (that one you posted in the youtube-link) next to the human outpost, which supposedly leads to the outside world.

When you open the door, it basically just triggers a cut scene where you get killed by an icy wind that blows in from the frozen world outside.

Comment: Wow, that's even better than the easter egg where you can kill Lord British in Ultima IX (which just makes the game unbeatable).